# my puppeteer not working on docker container

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

It was working fine on just development environment not docker container.
But not working on docker container. How do I setup puppeteer on docker container?
I have seen a lot of answer and question but not working at all. I think that my code is wrong..

My Env:

- OS: MacOS, M1

Here is Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN apk update && apk upgrade

RUN apk add --no-cache udev ttf-freefont chromium

ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true \
    CHROME_PATH=/usr/bin/chromium-browser \
    PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH=/usr/bin/chromium-browser

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 8120

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]
```

And docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  node:
    container_name: node-test
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    platform: linux/amd64
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    networks:
      - test-net
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "8010:8010"
    depends_on:
      - mongo

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo
    restart: always
    networks:
      - test-net
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: test
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: test

volumes:
  mongo:
networks:
  test-net:
    name: test-net
    external: true
```

crawler.ts:

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

export const crawler = async (url: string) => {
  console.log(url); // <- [v] working

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: false,
    executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser',
    headless: true,
    args:
      '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
      '--no-sandbox',
      '--disable-setuid-sandbox'
    ],
    slowMo: 30
  });
  console.log(browser) // [v] print something.
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  console.log(page); // <- [x] not working. print anything.
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 })
  await page.goto("https://www.example.com");

  await page.close();
  await browser.close();
};
```

My error message is different whenever modify my code, but It is latest error message on terminal.

```
node-test | ProtocolError: Protocol error (Target.createTarget): Target closed.
node-test |     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/src/common/Connection.ts:119:16
node-test |     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
node-test |     at Connection.send (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/src/common/Connection.ts:115:12)
node-test |     at Browser._createPageInContext (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/src/common/Browser.ts:525:47)
node-test |     at BrowserContext.newPage (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/src/common/Browser.ts:886:26)
node-test |     at Browser.newPage (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/src/common/Browser.ts:518:33)
node-test |     at crawler (/usr/src/app/src/crawler/crawler.ts:16:30)
node-test |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
node-test |     at async CrawlerController (/usr/src/app/src/crawler/crawler.controller.ts:10:5) {
node-test |   originalMessage: ''
node-test | }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what "not working" means here? What error message(s) or behavior lead you to conclude that it's not working?

Comment: @ggorien Thank you again! I will edit my question again include error messages.

Comment: @ggorien When I run `docker compose up --build` It works fine. My code run handling from request url to collect url's page metadata. but not working puppeteer  crawler correctly in background. In local machine, It worked fine:
But on docker container, anything show me. So, My Dockerfile or setting whether is correct or not, I want to check please.